# Ruby - Is it possible to create two different loops in the same "view" file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

I'm currently learning Ruby on Rails thanks to a website named codecademy, and I'm learning how to display informations from a database's array stocked into a variable

The exercice's correction is as shown below :

```
<div class="main movie-show">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="movie">

      <!-- Display the movie info here -->
      <div class="info">
        <%= image_tag @movie.image %>
        <h3 class="movie-title"><%= @movie.title %></h3>
        <p class="movie-release-year"><%= @movie.release_year %></p>
        <p class="movie-plot"><%= @movie.plot %></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <h2>Cast</h2>
    <% @actors.each do |actor| %>
      <div class="actor">
        <%= image_tag actor.image %>
        <h3 class="actor-name"><%= actor.first_name %> <%= actor.last_name %></h3>
        <p class="actor-bio"><%= actor.bio %></p>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see in the "movie" part that they directly take the variable to display the information needed, while they stock all the "actor" 's part in another |actor| variable

My question is the following, as I didn't find any satisfying answer online, is it possible to use two variables the same way in the same file ? Like using

```
<% @movies.each do |m| %>
```

and

```
<% @actors.each do |a| %>
```

Will it work anyway ? Will there be an error?

Comment: Please post your model associations and relavant controller code.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Not that will not be a problem, if your controller provides both the instance variable `@movies` and `@actors`

Comment: Yep, if you've defined an array or a collection you can loop through the elements in the array.

Comment: I think, you need add has_many :actors relation in movie model. But without controller code i'm not sure.

Comment: I didn't dare to try it, because I didn't want all the things I've done to f*ck up, but I just tried it and yes, it workd ^^' Thank you all for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use as many number of instance variables as you want in your view provided that they are properly defined in your controller code.

If you have defined both `@actors` and `@movies` instance variables in your controller action, then you can access then them in corresponding view. Remember: I wrote, corresponding view.

There is other way as well. For example, if you have defined relation between your `Movie` model and your `Actor` model, and the relation states that a movie can have many actors. In that case, you only need to instantiate `@movies` in your controller, and then you can access actors in the following way:

```
<% @movies.each do |movie| %>
   <% movie.actors.each do |actor| %>
     <%# All other relevant code %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In case, you don't know about relations, you can define them in following way:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :actors
end

class Actor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :movie
  # actors table should have a column named 'movie_id' for this to work
end
```